# Download Data from SQL in python

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I want to download data from SQL via python. But, instead of downloading the whole of dataset I only need specific variables.

I am **restricted** to use only the read_sql from pyodbc

My code is the following:

```
# call from SQL 
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect("""DRIVER={SQL Server};
                      Server=BXTS131133.eu.rabonet.com\LWID_LAB_03;
                      Database=CORP_Modelling;
                      Trusted_connection=yes;""")

SQL1 = 'SELECT * FROM [CORP_Modelling].[LDM_Freeze_1].[JointObligorMonthly]'
```

Nevertheless, suppose that I want to download only a few variables/attributes from SQL. For example, from the tables sepecified in 'SLQ1' I only want to download:

```
var_to_download = ['MeasurementPeriodID', 'JointObligorID' ]
```

I cannot understand how I can modify the above code in order to download only these variables.

Comment: Can't you just update your SELECT statement? `SELECT MeasurementPeriodID, JointObligorID FROM...`

Comment: Yes, it worked ! I was confused by the documentation. Thank you